# Is a metal chain inside a pc case a bad idea?

Tags: case, electric-shock

I have a pc case, sitting on wood, connected to a surge protector. I've put a metal chain into the case, one side connected to a random empty space in the case and the other side connected to the AIOs pipe, not pinching it or damaging it in anyway, fits perfectly. It's touching the guard thingy on top of the power and HDD Storage section. And its also touching  the graphics  card. Could this damage the pc? i use surge protector so i think it should be fine. Any ideas? thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: PC/Jewelry Case, interesting idea.

Comment: I had seen this post somewhere that a pc case was being held by chains around it, kinda like a wild animal. And seemed like such a cool thing to do but i had ugly chains till i got this one xD

Comment: @AdenAnderson This person used a plastic chain (and a bit of spray paint) which is much safer  https://preview.redd.it/nuj8rxwv2qq81.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=b0def3d7fe346761721e502f820dd58e3cadcc6f Leather and plastic are bad conductors.

Answer (score 4):

It can possibly create a short circuit. Magic smoke will escape and you're gonna have a bad time.

A proper surge protector protects the PC from electrical surges from the outside. It has no effect on stuff that's happening entirely on the "internal" side of the protector.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more? Like how can the short circuit happen? If it could happen on its own is it because of the chain touching somewhere? or charge differences?

Comment: @AdenAnderson Chain touching two metal contacts and shorting them. Everything metal in the case should be either permanently fixed or insulated. Even if it's not causing any shorts now, it's only a matter of time until someone bumps the case slightly. Dust buildup could mess things up too, I think.

Answer (score 1):

What could happen is, that the metal (conductive) chain touches some of the bare metal parts of your PC, when it is shaken/moved around. The surge protection only protects your system from power surges over your powerbar/plug, not from the inside. Everything on the inside is technically vulnerable. From how it looks right now though, I have no concerns. What should not happen is, that the chain comes on top of the graphics card, because then you would risk it sliding towards your mainboard and touching some exposed electronic components and short them, which would effectivly damage/kill your system. Just make sure, that when you want to move the chain, you turn off the power (actually unplug it), so if you accidentally touch any important parts on your boards, they aren't powered.
If your system is standing like so and is not moved much, then you should be good to go :)

I am adding to this: Usually, nothing unnecessary should be inside your casing. This is the safest way to go. But I understand why you're doing this and I think the risk is acceptable in that case.
I would judge that differently if this wasn't a mini ITX board, becuase it would have too much overhang under the GPU for that metal chain to touch easily. But since this is mini ITX, it's fine.

Comment: damn why is it always so touchy feely when it comes to electronics lol
I mean like i know putting a metal chain inside a pc case isnt exactly the first thing popping in mind when you think about improving aesthetics, but cmon its just a chain xD
I'll just put this thing outside the case just to be safe, i cant afford  another pc

Comment: @AdenAnderson Materials that do not allow electricity to pass easily through them (insulators) would be far safer. Still not recommended, but far safer. But make sure they can't move.

Comment: Also, keep in mind, electricity that goes through a cable is not just electricity. Electricity produces a magnetic field too. This is how its possible to have wireless electricity detectors, and that's also how induction works. Electric charge could build up on the metal cable over a long time if the cable is not grounded and if that metal cable then touches any part it should not, it will discharge. Could be a shock that could melt something or worse...

Comment: @LPChip concidering that even a short will most probably kill your system, I don't think you would have to worry about ESD too much.
And the capacitance of a metal chain is basically zero. So I doubt, that it will accumulate enough charge to actually do something.